# No sound from headphones on Ubuntu 18.04 with Realtek ALC668

Tags: 18.04, sound, kde, headphones, realtek

I've fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 but my headphones don't work at all.

My sound card is a Realtek ALC668

driver : Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.15.0-23-generic.

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [1043:158f]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Originally I had another issue - speakers had sound but volume was always on max level (changing seek bar didn't do anything), I solved this by reinstalling `alsa` but headphones still don't work.

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

`dmesg | grep audio`

```
[    4.758469] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.809446] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC668: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.809449] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.809451] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.809452] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.809453] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    4.809455] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
```

`dmesg | grep realtek`

```
[    4.809446] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC668: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.809449] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.809451] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.809452] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.809453] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    4.809455] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
```

[Full `dmesg` output](https://pastebin.com/raw/0WwXVaiH).

Comment: Add to your post the following command output: `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A2`

Comment: @abu_bua post updated

Comment: Do you see Headphones profile under the Output tab in Settings->Sound after you plug in your headphone?

Comment: @BernardWei yes ( speaker and headphone ) also when i connect headphone speaker disables ( in front of speakers "unavailable" appears )

Comment: Is this the whole output of lspci... ? This is the onboard audio chip and driver! Did you try my answer?  For shorthand try `lspci` .

Comment: @abu_bua i rerun the command, yes same output , also edited the post with lspci output

Comment: In your post you mentioned that you are using a Realtek ACL 668 card. I don't see it on the lspci output. Did you tried to reboot your machine ?

Comment: @abu_bua i rebooted my machine still same results. i figured my sound card model out by running alsamixer

Comment: Since you have alsamixer, can you check that the headphone volume is not muted or set to zero? Kinda obvious things to check but thought I ask if you haven't already done that.

Comment: @BernardWei i double checked it ( even after and before connecting the headphone )

Comment: Does syslog or dmesg provide any more clues when you connect and disconnect the head phone? In addition, alsa-info does provide more data but the output is pretty long and hard to debug. Someone familar with it may be ablt to decipher the info if you provide that.

Comment: @BernardWei i ran these two commands : dmesg | grep audio & dmesg | grep realtek ( output in edited post ) also be connecting and disconnecting headphone there is no change in dmesg output

Comment: That's good @Sahandevs , it shouldn't report any error if things are working. That's bad also, as it could also meant the problem is more subtle and hard to debug.

Comment: @BernardWei i also tried editing alsa-conf and using jackretasking , no chances

Comment: @Sahandevs As a long shot, may be you can try doing what this guy did for his sound trouble. Something about diabling HDMI audio seems to snap the hw back to working state for the headphone jack. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-sound-only-when-headphones-plugged-in/50689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue:

Check device configurations in Pulseaudio volume control

```
pavucontrol -t 5
```

If you are not using **Built-in** input device, change it from *duplex* to *output*

Also change any webcam/microphone to *input* only and reduce playback devices.

Maybe you'll find the nvidia card is detected in there but set to *off*.

For the output switching when plugging in USB mic, check what Pulseaudio modules are loaded:

```
pactl list short modules
```

There might be `module-switch-on-connect` showing in 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Open **setup** and click on the left side **sound**.

On the bottom select profile, and try other ones. Click on Test Speakers to test your profile.